# Magento2: Payment method is not showing on checkout page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

The payment method is not showing on the checkout page.

[image]

**console error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order
b2aee5ee1e36f296863f6f91b53a4ae9.min.js:16 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (b2aee5ee1e36f296863f6f91b53a4ae9.min.js:16)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (b2aee5ee1e36f296863f6f91b53a4ae9.min.js:112)
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's that kind of hard issue. We cannot see the actual error on browser console. I suggest you that we need to set a debug breakpoint in error Js script.

Comment: Can you give th precise version of your Magento2?

Comment: Magento v2.0.17 @mohamed

Comment: @Mohamed23gharbi Please check my version